# Setting `withForceGlobalBucketAccessEnabled(true)` will ensure the S3 call will not fail, even if the S3 bucket is in another Region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Setting `withForceGlobalBucketAccessEnabled(true)` like:

`AmazonS3 amazonS3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
withForceGlobalBucketAccessEnabled(true).build();`

By setting withForceGlobalBucketAccessEnabled(true):

1.) Will it ensure that even if the bucket is not in the same region as provided in `withRegion(Regions)` that call (Read/Write) to S3 will not fail?

2.) If the bucket is not in the same region as provided in `withRegion(Regions)` then the bucket will be searched in another regions. After getting the bucket's region, it will be cached. So actually it will add the latency in the first call only, afterwards, it will use the cached region **NOT** the region provided in `withRegion(Regions.XXX)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If withForceGlobalBucketAccessEnabled is set to true, i.e. withForceGlobalBucketAccessEnabled(true), then first the call will be made to the region specified. If the bucket is not in that region then it will search the bucket in other regions. Once the bucket is found (in the specified region or in any other region) then that region will be cached. So logically, if the bucket's region is not changed and your service is not bounced then if even you've specified the wrong region in the code, then also the vall will be made to the correct region (which is cached.)